# Order parameter not functional

Tags: bug, status-completed

#### Consider these two API calls:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?pagesize=1&sort=votes&order=desc
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?pagesize=1&sort=votes&order=asc

They're the same except for the order parameter. However, the same thing is returned (even for greater values of `pagesize`) -- it seems questions are always ordered descending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  `order` should be respected on any method that takes a `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Order does nothing for `/questions`, `/questions/tagged/{tags}` and `/questions/unanswered`. I think this is by design, but now that I think about it I don't know why the `order` parameter is listed in the documentation for them (other than consistency with everything else that takes `sort`).